# checkbox selection & arrays

Tags: php

I have 9 check boxes in my select.php

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="g1[]" id="c1" value="c1">
<input type="checkbox" name="g1[]" id="c2" value="c2">
<input type="checkbox" name="g1[]" id="c3" value="c3">

<input type="checkbox" name="g2[]" id="h1" value="h1">
<input type="checkbox" name="g2[]" id="h2" value="h2">
<input type="checkbox" name="g2[]" id="h3" value="h3">

<input type="checkbox" name="g3[]" id="d1" value="d1">
<input type="checkbox" name="g3[]" id="d2" value="d2">
<input type="checkbox" name="g3[]" id="d3" value="d3">
</form>
```

ok my test.php looks like this now:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$g1 = $_POST['g1']; 
$g2 = $_POST['g2']; 
$g3 = $_POST['g3'];

//Connect to DB

$ng1 = count($g1);
$ng2 = count($g2);
$ng3 = count($g3);

 $sum = 0; 
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) 
 { 
     $arr = "g$i"; 
     if (!isset($_POST[$arr])) 
         ${$arr} = array(); 
     else 
         ${$arr} = $_POST[$arr]; 
     if (!is_array(${$arr})) 
         die("Error in input parameter $arr"); 
     ${"ng$i"} = count(${$arr}); 
     if (${"ng$i"} < 1) 
         die("At least one $arr checkbox must be checked"); 
     $sum += ${"ng$i"}; 

     ${"g$i"."_sql"} = implode(',', array_map(${$arr}, 'mysql_real_escape')); 
 } 

 $query="INSERT INTO ch_lg (g1, g2, g3) VALUES ('$g1_sql','$g2_sql','$g3_sql')"; 

 mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_close(); 

//echo message
}
```

**Modifid Question**

I need to check that:

1. The user chose 1 checkbox from each array (your code does this)
2. He didn't select more than 4 checkboxes (your code does this)
3. He chose 1 more checkbox from JUST one array (meaning that he has to chose 4 in total and that just 1 of each is not acceptable) - I think this is not happening in your code. Does it?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't `"action=test.php"` be `action="test.php"`?

Comment: sorry yes... typing mistake. ty

Comment: I think your IFs are wrong. "At least one in each array": so if (($ng1 < 1) || ($ng2 < 1) || ($ng3 < 1)) die("At least one in each array"); and "no more than three": if (($ng1+$ng2+$ng3)>3) die("No more than three"). Finally, isn't this condition the same as "ng1, ng2, ng3 must all be EXACTLY EQUAL TO ONE?"

Comment: @Iserni So I have to change the way of "thinking" to get the same result? I have to use just 1 IF for each of my checks?

Comment: @lserni I have edited my code. But still have problems. ty

Answer (score 2):

"No more than 3 in both of them" means that 2 hair + 1 color is OK, but 2 hair + 2 color is not because it would give 4? Then:

```
$ncolor = count($color);
$nhair   = count($hair);
if (($ncolor >= 1) && ($nhair >=1) && (($ncolorn+$nhair)<=3))
   // OK
else
   // No good.
```

> and then insert my values into db columns COLOR / HAIR.

You have to explain how your DB is structured and how do you want the data. If I get 2 hair and 1 color, do you want:

- 3 rows, one with color, two with hair
- 2 rows, one with color and hair, one with hair alone
- 1 row with colors and hairs coalesced with separators:

  $color_sql = implode(',', array_map($color, 'mysql_real_escape'));
     $hair_sql  = implode(',', array_map($hair,  'mysql_real_escape'));

  INSERT INTO mytable (..., color, hair, ...) 
         VALUES (...,'$color_sql','$hair_sql', ...);

Also, at the beginning of test.php I assume there is something like:

```
<?php
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     $g1 = $_POST['g1'];
     $g2 = $_POST['g2'];
     $g3 = $_POST['g3'];

     ...
```

Verification could be done in a cycle:

```
<?php
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     $sum = 0;
     for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
     {
         $arr = "g$i";
         if (!isset($_POST[$arr]))
             ${$arr} = array();
         else
             ${$arr} = $_POST[$arr];
         if (!is_array(${$arr}))
             die("Error in input parameter $arr");
         ${"ng$i"} = count(${$arr});
         if (${"ng$i"} < 1)
             die("At least one $arr checkbox must be checked");
         $sum += ${"ng$i"};

         ${"g$i"."_sql"} = implode(',', array_map(${$arr}, 'mysql_real_escape'));
     }

     // NOTICE: 'NULL' between quotes? Should't it be NULL without quotes?
     // If ID is autoincrement, just omit it: (g1, g2, g3) VALUES ('$g1_sql',...)

     $query="INSERT INTO ch_lg (ID, g1, g2, g3) VALUES ('NULL','$g1_sql','$g2_sql','$g3_sql')";

     mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_close();
```

Comment: can I have 1 row in my db and a coloumn HAIR that will take bot balues e.g 1,2

Comment: @pavlos1316 `$color_string = implode(',', $color)` will convert them to such a string, `explode(',', $color_string)` would convert it back.  That may or may not be a good solution; I think there's still a little confusion as to what you're trying to achieve and why.

Comment: Yes, but now you are using *three* cb arrays, not two. This changes the behaviour of the IFs. See comment to the other thread.

Comment: @lserni I have {$g1 = $_POST['g1'];} in the beggining of my code. As for the verification code, I need to check for 4 things. 1. If user didn't select at least 1 cb from each array, 2. if he has select exactly 1 from each array, 3. if he has selected 1 from each array and a second one from just one array (here i insert to db) and 4. if he has selected more than one cb in each array. and I understant it better with my code. I don't quite understant what we are checking with yours.

Comment: Of course your code seems better and less lines, but how can I check for all 3 options? ty

Comment: The code already checks -- the options are called g1, g2 and g3, so I put a cycle with i = 1,2,3 and "build" a variable reference; that's what ${"g$i"} does. ${"g$i"} is $g1 when $i == 1, $g2 when $i == 2 and so on. The cycle saves the final SQL form of each option into sg{$i}_sql, i.e. sg1_sql, sg2_sql, sg3_sql :-) . Haven't tested yet, but this syntax always worked for me.

Comment: So to make it clear... The code will check if... 1. there is no array that user havent selected anything, 2. there is ONLY one array that the user made 2 selections and not more?

Comment: @lserni I just edited my initial post. can you check it please? ty